# Is biometric data inevitably collected when obtaining a UK student visa regardless of the channel of obtaining it or other factors?

Tags: visas, uk

Is biometric data inevitably collected when obtaining a UK student visa regardless of the channel of obtaining it or other factors? And does the nationality of the visa applicant make any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is.  “You’ll need to have your fingerprints and photograph taken at a visa application centre (to get a biometric residence permit) as part of your application.”

Source: https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa/apply